# Trouble enabling webusb in chrome

Tags: api, google-chrome, navigator, webusb

I'm trying to enable webusb feature in chrome to test it. I' tryng to run this demo (https://github.com/webusb/arduino) locally on my webserver but it does not work, instead the version published on github works.

My setup:

- Apache webserver virtual host with ssl support with self signed certificate
- Last Google Chrome with webusb and experimental api flags enabled
- Imported selfsigned certificate in Chrome to made it trust it like a valid cerficate
- Remove origin trials meta from demo

But when I access the demo page I got javascript error because navigator.usb is undefined.

What's wrong in my setup, why navigator.usb is not enabled in my local setup but is enabled when I surf the online demo from the same browser?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To get it up and running you have to enable *Experimental Web Platform features*, you can find these in the Chrome flags:

[chrome://flags/#enable-experimental-web-platform-features](http://chrome://flags/#enable-experimental-web-platform-features)

Now `navigator.usb` will be available, however, if you're developing on `localhost` you wont see any devices. To get devices showing up you should boot Chrome with `--disable-webusb-security` which will produce a notification announcing that security will suffer and allow you to see al your attached devices. For more extensive explanation take a look at https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/03/access-usb-devices-on-the-web

Comment: Hello, I have tried to follow the steps in the link you gave "for more extensive explanation" but no luck, requestDevice(... filters ... blah blah blah ... vendorId ...) gives error message "SecurityError: Must be handling a user gesture to show a permission request." and getDevices() returns with 0 devices.

chrome Version 58.0.3029.96 (64-bit)

and running chrome from bat file:
TASKKILL /F /IM chrome.exe
start chrome.exe --args --disable-web-security --user-data-dir="c:/chromedev"

Comment: There should be a user interaction before trying to do anything, most of the times this means you should initiate the connection after a button press or something similar.

Comment: my device is just a custom NFC reader for our NFC tags that collect data, no buttons on it, we have a desktop app that sends a message to the reader for the reader be able to start scanning tags, but without a handle on the device i'm not sure how to send that message to the reader. when I was working with chrome.serial i was able to get the handle for the device (but chrome.serial is being phased out so we don't want to use it), thought maybe they deprecated something for this version since its still experimental.

Comment: Ok, i figured it out, i was using the API wrong, needed to wait for getDevices to finish before i use requestDevice. so my order of method calls is: addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded'){navigator.usb.getDevices()} than a button click will do the navigator.usb.requestDevice method. my error i think was the getDevices din't finish before the requestDevice was reached (getDevices probably runs on another thread?).

Comment: alright, im having sort of a face palm moment, i am now trying to call the open() method, but its returning an error: SecurityError: Access denied. i have tried opening chrome with flags '--disable-webusb-security' and '--disable-web-security' (the webusb flag is not on the chrome flags list here: [link](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/)) is that flag perhaps removed now? i have found this [link](chrome://usb-internals/) to add test devices but was unable to get it to work with any of the test devices i made.

Comment: When on Ubuntu I ran into my user not owning the connection giving me exactly that error. You can change it using `sudo chown group:user /dev/ttyACM0` (fill in your address and user/group)